# How to get a value in a multidimensional array using a string as multidimensional index?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

if I have a string like this , `$index_string="[1][3]";`

How to get value in below array using above string,

`$value_I_want_to_get_using_above_string = $multidimensional_array[$index_string];`

Comment: Not clear what you want exactly ?

Comment: Are you creating $index_string variable or are you receiving it from somewhere? The reason I ask is, there can possibly be a simpler solution if you were creating it.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I'm receiving it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this using [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

```
$index_string="[1][3]";
$index_string =' $value_I_want_to_get_using_above_string = $multidimensional_array'.$index_string;;
eval($index_string);
```

Although as we all know `eval()` is dangerous especially if you are getting that string from another place.

Comment: thank you for thee answer , I think this is what I wanted , By the way why `eval` is dangerous.(I'm getting the value from my own database)

Comment: `eval` is dangerous since it executes a php code, so the place you are getting your string from could inject malicious php code.

Comment: Im getting this error , @Ryad.iv Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in  : eval()'d code on line 1